# how to page down when running top?

Tags: terminal

When running top in terminal, I can't find a way to scroll down to view all running processes (save for resizing the window, but even then I can't display all). I tried setting and using the page down key command in the preferences, but that didn't work.

Anyone know how to scroll down in the list of processes in top?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, `top` is not scrollable; you're meant to sort the process list to shorten it to what you want.

`htop` is a more-powerful alternative that is scrollable. Here's how to [install it on Mac OS X](http://themainframe.ca/2011/06/29/install-htop-on-mac-os-x/).

Or, you could use Activity Monitor from /Applications/Utilities.